# What is the type of letter $\mathbb {A,B,C,D,...}$ called

Tags: notation

$\mathbb {N,P,Q,R,Z}$ all represent commonly used sets of numbers, but I can't find any good references on what they're called. I've tried double bar, double stroke, and googling what the ____ number symbol was called; inserting for integers, primes, etc.

What is it called?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold

Comment: thanks! extra letters

Comment: Some people prefer to use plain bold, e.g., $\textbf Z$ rather than $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I'd argue that this post is on topic (and you should vote to reopen if you have the rep), because mathematical writing is part of mathematics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer isn't authoritative, but I've always heard them called "blackboard" or "blackboard bold" letters. Note that the TeX command is \mathbb, where the "bb" stands for "blackboard."